# Is it possible to use an Intel Q8400 CPU in my ASUS P5N-EM HDMI mobo?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core2

I have an [ASUS P5N-EM HDMI](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=JybbnPOSpalWtSQa) motherboard. Currently, it's using an oldish P4 cpu. Works fine.

I just received a spankin' new Core2 Quad Processor Q8400 a few mins ago. Unopened, in the box.

I have no idea if this cpu will work in my motherboard. My motherboard is a Socket LGA775, though. I'm running the latest BIOS (for my mobo) which is version 4.01. That said, I don't think the CPU is listed on any documentation. I'm worried that it won't work .. and if so .. why would that be?! The mobo is around 8 months old, i think.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processor probably just wasn't out when the motherboard was made, it should work fine.

CONFIRMED: It's compatible with all Core 2 Quad processors.

Comment: El wikidio :) Cheers! I'll post back in a few days with luck/failure :)

Comment: Yep - works great :) I've also *lapped* my CPU and Heatsink and it all works :)

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed from the ASUS page for your board:

[image]

[image] [image]

> **LGA775 Intel® Core™2 Processor Ready**
>   This motherboard supports the latest Intel® Core™2 processors in LGA775 package. It also can support Intel® next generation 45nm Multi-Core CPU.

---

The [**CPU-Upgrades list for your motherboard: ASUS P5N-EM HDMI**](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-ASUS/P5N-EM_HDMI.html),
last updated **Mar 2, 2009**, does not show **Q8400**, though it shows **E8400**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [NewEgg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131229)'s product page for this motherboard.  It looks like you should be able to use your new CPU!

Here are the Cliff's Notes:

```
Supported CPU
CPU Socket Type     LGA 775
CPU Type    Core 2 Quad / Core 2 Extreme / Core 2 Duo
FSB     1333/1066MHz
Supported CPU Technologies  Hyper-Threading Technology
```

-JFV